# List rearranged

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very long list from which I will display part of it as,

```
a={{1, {3, 5, 8, 9}}, {2, {4, 6}}, {6, {1}}, {10, {1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}}};
```

For plotting purposes, I would like to rewrite the list in the following form

```
a = {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 
1}, {10, 3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}} ; ListPlot[a];
```

Since the actual list is extremely long, I appreciate it if you can help me in doing this. Please keep in mind that the first number is associated with one or more other numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `Join` and `Thread`:

```
Join @@ Thread /@ a
(* {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, {10, 3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}} *)
```

Comment: oh this one is smooth

Comment: Flatten[Thread /@ a, 1] this could also be a good alternative.

Answer (score 7):

I am sure there are at least 10 ways to do this in Mathematica. One that comes to mind now is

```
a={{1, {3, 5, 8, 9}}, {2, {4, 6}}, {6, {1}}, {10, {1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}}};
Flatten[Cases[a, {x_, {y___}} :> ({x, #} & /@ {y})], 1]
```

gives

```
{{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, {10,
   3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Map[Splice@*Thread] @ a
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, 
>  {10, 3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}}
> ```

Also

```
Splice @* Thread /@ a  (* thanks: LukasLang *)
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, 
>  {10, 3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}}
> ```

For versions older than 12.0 replace `Splice` with `Apply[Sequence]`.

Comment: Thanks to the precedence of `@*`, you could also use `Splice@*Thread /@ a`

Comment: Thank you @LukasLang.; excellent point. Added your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

```
a//Table[Splice@Distribute[#[[i]],List], {i,1,Length@#}]& 

(* {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, {10,   3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}}  *)
```

**Update**

```
Level[Thread /@ a, {2}]

(* {1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, {10, 3}, 
   {10, 5},{10, 6},{10, 7},{10, 8}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{1, {3, 5, 8, 9}}, {2, {4, 6}}, {6, {1}}, {10, {1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}}};
```

Using `Cases` and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
Cases[list, x : {__} :> Splice @ Thread @ x]
```

{{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, {10,
3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, {3, 5, 8, 9}}, {2, {4, 6}}, {6, {1}}, {10, {1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. {a_, b : {__}} :> Splice@Tuples@{{a}, b}
```

> {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {10, 1}, {10,
> 3}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}}